# check if type has or inherit a type that has a certain attribute

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm trying to check if a type has the [DataContract] attribute defined or inherits a type that has it defined

for instance:

```
[DataContract]
public class Base
{
}


public class Child : Base
{
}

// IsDefined(typeof(Child), typeof(DataContract)) should be true;
```

the Attribute.IsDefined, and Attribute.GetCustomAttribute doesn't look at the base class

anybody knows how to do this without looking at the BaseClasses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public static bool IsDefined(Type t, Type attrType)
{
    do {
        if (t.GetCustomAttributes(attrType, true).Length > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        t = t.BaseType;
    } while (t != null);
    return false;
}
```

---

I got the idea to make it with a recursive call because of the term "recursion" in your comment. Here is an extension method

```
public static bool IsDefined(this Type t, Type attrType)
{
    if (t == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return 
        t.GetCustomAttributes(attrType, true).Length > 0 ||
        t.BaseType.IsDefined(attrType);
}
```

call it like this

```
typeof(Child).IsDefined(typeof(DataContractAttribute))
```

Comment: Of course, if you want to check the _interfaces_ implemented by the type, and all their base interfaces recursively, it's a little more complex. But that's outside the question asked, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

There is an overload on the `GetCustomAttribute()` and `GetCustomAttributes(bool inherit)` methods that takes a bool value whether to do a search in inherited classes. However, it will only work if the attribute you are searching for was defined with the `[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.?, Inherited = true)]` attribute.